# Defining a Chef ERB template method

Tags: templates, chef-infra, erb

Chef is great for provisioning basic templates, but I'm looking to incorporate more advanced templating logic. Is something like this possible:

```
<%
def say_hi()
-%>
  <%= "hi" %>
<%
end
-%>

# Extraneous template data here

<% say_hi() -%> # Call to template method
```

In this example, I would expect that `hi` would be generated whenever `say_hi()` is called, but it is not working.

Is this behavior possible and if not, is there a way to produce similar behavior? I assume Chef templates follow generic ERB templating rules.

Thanks!

**Update: A Little Bit of Backstory**

I am trying to templatize a very complicated `config.yml` that has it's own formatting scheme. It looks something like this:

```
key: value

some other key:
  - some other value
  - another value

hash-like key:
  hash-like value:
    - element A
    - element B
```

There are so many of these, I thought instead of mapping attributes directly in-line, I would define them all under a common key and loop through them:

```
<% node['section']['help'].each do |key, value| -%>
  <%= "#{key}: #{value}" %>
<% end -%>
```

And this works great! It keeps me from having to define everything twice (once in the attributes file and once in the template), however I felt this structure was getting out of hand, especially for nested hashes in arrays:

```
<% node['section']['help'].each do |key, value| -%>
  <% if value.kind_of?(Hash) -%>
    <%= "#{key}: "%>
    <% value.each do |subkey, subvalue| -%>
      <%= "  #{subkey}: #{subvalue}" %>
    <% end -%>

  <% else -%>
    <%= "#{key}: #{value}" %>
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

So I wanted to create a recursive method to identify the three types (normal value, array value, and hash value) and deal with the formatting of each. The full method I prototyped looks something like this:

```
<%
def determine_type(key, value, iteration)

  if value.kind_of?(Hash)
    -%>
    <%= %Q(#{" " * (iteration * 2)} #{key}:)  %>

    <% value.keys do |subkey, subvalue| -%>
      <% determine_type(subkey, subvalue, iteration + 1) -%>
    <% end -%>
    <%
  elsif value.kind_of?(Array)
    -%>
    <%= %Q(#{" " * (iteration * 2)} #{key}:)  %>

    <% value.each do |subvalue| -%>
      <%= %Q(#{" " * ((iteration + 1) * 2)} - #{subvalue})  %>
    <% end -%>
    <%
  else
    -%>
    <%= %Q(#{" " * (iteration * 2)} #{key}: #{value})  %>
    <%
  end
end
-%>
```

And it's called here:

```
<% node['section']['help'].each do |key, value| -%>
  <% determine_type(key, value, 1) -%>
<% end -%>
```

Sadly, if can only return values and not output directly to the ERB template, this relatively elegant strategy breaks.

Comment: Did you try it ? What was the output ? What is the use case ? (I really can't see where this could be of use). With so few description of the attempted goal, it's impossible to know if variables or partial template could be of use.

Comment: I've found it to be very hard to maintain templates long term when they start to have this much logic in them. It's much easier to read when the templates are simple and the logic is in a recipe or library called by a recipe.

Comment: The function should return string and you should print the result of the function with `=` like that `<%= say_hi %>`. But having logic and functions in templates is a bad idea. Just create another template and have a logic in recipe for which template to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a recommended design pattern.  Logic should be kept in the recipes and resources.  That said it is possible which is the meat of your question and what has peaked my interest

```rb
<%
def say_hi()
-%>
  <% "hi" %>
<%
end
-%>
# Extraneous template data here

<%= say_hi() -%> # Call to template method
```

which will render the following file

```
# Extraneous template data here

hi # Call to template method
```

Notice how the `<%=` block takes the return value of `say_hi` and prints it, instead of printing from the `say_hi` function itself.

This means that your function needs to return the entire string that you would like it to produce and that you can't use template tags within the method. I would say that restriction alone defeats the purpose of using functions/methods in the erb templates.

However, It would be interesting if `render` was a function that you could use to render a different partial template... I just looked this up and low and behold `render 'other_template.erb'` works like a charm!

So given this, I would still recommend sticking to keeping logic in the recipes and only use loops, conditions, and prints in the templates.  I am not sure what the guidelines on using `render` in templates is, but I have a feeling that it is discouraged.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've also seen `render` used before, but I'm not sure if that would provide the functionality I'm looking for. I edited my question to include more relevant background as to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JamesTaylor If it is just YAML I normally just have a namespace of the node attributes be for that config file and then I just dump that hash using `YAML::dump(node['mycookbook']['myconfig'].to_hash)`  It is normally the easiest way of doing it and pretty clear to the end user of the cookbook, who probably already has the structure of the apps config file in their heads.

Comment: There is a bit of a trick that you need though to deal if you go that route... the problem is with deeply nested node attributes. You need to convert the node attribute to JSON then back to a basic hash then to YAML... crazy but it works great 

`YAML.dump(JSON.parse(node['mycookbook']['myconfig'].to_hash.to_json))`